# LEFT OUTER JOIN not producing full output on time series CTE using generate_series (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, generate-series

I was hoping to have a CTE that generated some time series data (hourly values based on min / max timestamp values pulled from another table) then doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN on a table of transaction data (where the transaction timestamp has been reduced to the same hourly format in the time series CTE)

Here's my current query for this postgresql database (it the tables are read-only views)

```sql
WITH time_series AS (
    SELECT
        date_trunc('hours', dd) AS open_hour,
        -- dow starts on Sunday=0 ... Saturday=6
        CASE extract(DOW FROM date_trunc('hours', dd))::INTEGER
            WHEN 0 THEN '0 Sunday'
            WHEN 1 THEN '1 Monday'
            WHEN 2 THEN '2 Tuesday'
            WHEN 3 THEN '3 Wednesday'
            WHEN 4 THEN '4 Thursday'
            WHEN 5 THEN '5 Friday'
            WHEN 6 THEN '6 Saturday'
        END AS transaction_day
    FROM
        -- the time series is generated from the min, and max timestamps 
        -- from the table, `circ_trans`
        generate_series(
            --'2021-12-09 17:00:00.000 -0500'::TIMESTAMP,
            (
                SELECT transaction_gmt
                FROM
                    sierra_view.circ_trans
                WHERE
                    id IN (
                        SELECT min(id)
                        FROM
                            sierra_view.circ_trans
                        WHERE
                            sierra_view.circ_trans.op_code = 'o'
                    )
            ),
            --'2022-06-08 08:00:00.000 -0400'::TIMESTAMP,
            (
                SELECT transaction_gmt
                FROM
                    sierra_view.circ_trans
                WHERE
                    id IN (
                        SELECT max(id)
                        FROM
                            sierra_view.circ_trans
                        WHERE
                            sierra_view.circ_trans.op_code = 'o'
                    )
            ),
            '1 hour'::INTERVAL
        ) AS dd
    WHERE
        extract(HOUR FROM date_trunc('hours', dd))::INTEGER BETWEEN 8 AND 22
)
SELECT
        ct.branch_name,
    time_series.open_hour AS open_hour_timestamp,
    time_series.transaction_day,
    extract(
        HOUR FROM date_trunc('hours', time_series.open_hour)
    )::INTEGER AS hour,
    date(time_series.open_hour) AS open_date,
    count(ct.item_record_id) AS count_checkouts,
    count(DISTINCT ct.patron_record_id) AS count_distinct_patrons
FROM
    time_series
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ct1.item_record_id,
        ct1.patron_record_id,
        bn."name" AS branch_name,
        date_trunc(
            'hours', ct1.transaction_gmt
        ) AS transaction_hour
    FROM sierra_view.circ_trans AS ct1
    INNER JOIN sierra_view.statistic_group AS sg ON sg.code_num = ct1.stat_group_code_num
    INNER JOIN sierra_view.location AS l ON l.code = sg.location_code
    INNER JOIN sierra_view.branch AS b ON b.code_num = l.branch_code_num
    INNER JOIN sierra_view.branch_name AS bn ON bn.branch_id = b.id
    WHERE
        ct1.op_code = 'o'
        -- non-admin cardtypes
        AND ct1.ptype_code::INTEGER < 196
) AS ct ON ct.transaction_hour = time_series.open_hour
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

What I'm expecting to see is something along the lines of

| branch_name | open_hour_timestamp | transaction_day | hour | open_date | count_checkouts | count_distinct_patrons |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 08:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 8 | 2021-12-12 | 0 | 0 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 09:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 9 | 2021-12-12 | 0 | 0 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 10:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 10 | 2021-12-12 | 0 | 0 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 11:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 11 | 2021-12-12 | 0 | 0 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 12:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 12 | 2021-12-12 | 0 | 0 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 13:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 13 | 2021-12-12 | 9 | 5 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 14:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 14 | 2021-12-12 | 1 | 1 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 15:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 15 | 2021-12-12 | 2 | 2 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 16:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 16 | 2021-12-12 | 1 | 1 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 17:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 17 | 2021-12-12 | 0 | 0 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 18:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 18 | 2021-12-12 | 0 | 0 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 19:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 19 | 2021-12-12 | 0 | 0 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 20:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 20 | 2021-12-12 | 0 | 0 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 21:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 21 | 2021-12-12 | 0 | 0 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 22:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 22 | 2021-12-12 | 0 | 0 |

... but what I'm actually getting back is this:

| branch_name | open_hour_timestamp | transaction_day | hour | open_date | count_checkouts | count_distinct_patrons |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 13:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 13 | 2021-12-12 | 9 | 5 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 14:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 14 | 2021-12-12 | 1 | 1 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 15:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 15 | 2021-12-12 | 2 | 2 |
| Anderson | 2021-12-12 16:00:00.000 -0500 | 0 Sunday | 16 | 2021-12-12 | 1 | 1 |

It almost appears as if the LEFT OUTER JOIN is just not working in the way you'd expect it too--it appears to be throwing away the values on the left when it doesn't match what's being joined... unless I'm just missing something else here.

Here's a link to the query and a bit more output:
[github gist to query + output](https://gist.github.com/rayvoelker/4ddaf0b12c5673871acbe559bbb0578a)

Comment: Don't you need to join on date+hour and not just hour?

Comment: a dbfiddle with all tables and data would help much more to ave a [mre]

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking about trying to produce a set of data where this produces similar output in one of those reproducible kinda ways. It's certainly hard to see in a somewhat complex query like this

Comment: @shawnt00 the JOIN (and LEFT OUTER JOIN _should_) works because the CTE produces a value for open_hour (output of date_trunc()) that can be matched to the output of `date_trunc()` on the transaction_gmt (the more precise timestamp of the transaction)

Comment: Yes, I didn't look close enough to see that those were still date values. I believe the problem is that you're grouping by `branch_name` which is going to be null when no data matched up to that window.

Comment: @shawnt00 I was expecting there to be null values in that table (as that table won't generate data for those hours--again, fully expected) .. but that shouldn't matter when doing the LEFT OUTER JOIN since i'd expect it to retain ALL rows from that left set (the complete / full time series)

Comment: If there's no data then there's no branch name. You want to do a cross product of your time series against all possible branches. Then when you join do it on both columns. The data you wanted to see is being aggregated as a null branch name which isn't the results you've shared.